# How to have expanding tableview cell align itself to show entire cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a tableview that employs cells that expand to reveal more content. When the cells expand, however, they expand off the screen so the user has to scroll to see the entire cell. Is there a way to have the tableview cell auto-align in the visible window to have the cell be totally visible when it expands? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. All that is needed in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is -

```
tableView.scrollRectToVisible(tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath), animated: true)
```